# Addition and multiplication of python using single coefficient

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to add and multiply polynomials using python .
For example, if the Question is:

```
addpoly([(4,3),(3,0)],[(-4,3),(2,1)])
[(2, 1),(3, 0)] (answer)
```

my Code:

```
def addpoly( x, y):
 min_len = min( len(x), len(y))
 return x[: -min_len] + y[: -min_len] + [ x[i] + y[i] for i in range(-min_len,0)
```

my output

```
addpoly([(4,3),(3,0)],[(-4,3),(2,1)])
[(4, 3, -4, 3), (3, 0, 2, 1)]
```

Required Output:

```
[(2, 1), (3, 0)]
```

I would like to recieve any suggestions if possible.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for *specific* questions, not vague suggestion requests. Please edit your question to ask a clear question or you should not get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to convert your polynomial into a `dict` with `power -> coefficient` items:

```
In [1]: p1 = [(4,3),(3,0)]

In [2]: p2 = [(-4,3),(2,1)]

In [3]: from collections import Counter

In [4]: p1_c = Counter(dict((degree, coef) for (coef, degree) in p1))

In [5]: p2_c = Counter(dict((degree, coef) for (coef, degree) in p2))

In [6]: p1_c, p2_c
Out[6]: (Counter({0: 3, 3: 4}), Counter({1: 2, 3: -4}))
```

Then you could add these dictionaries:

```
In [7]: p1_c + p2_c
Out[7]: Counter({0: 3, 1: 2})
```

And convert them back into a list:

```
In [8]: [(c, d) for (d, c) in (p1_c + p2_c).items()]
Out[8]: [(3, 0), (2, 1)]
```

You may also sort them by the degree (to fit your expected output)

```
In [9]: from operator import itemgetter

In [10]: sorted(((c, d) for (d, c) in (p1_c + p2_c).items()), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
Out[10]: [(2, 1), (3, 0)]
```

You may also find useful [`sympy`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/polys/reference.html) library, it allows you to work with symbolic expressions (i.e. with polynomials too) in a very neat way.